# Transparent texture in pointCloudMaterial and depth-buffer

Tags: three.js, textures

I use threejs to add a pointCloud to the screen , and set texture map, But I find that the top point can cover the one behind it.

[image]

after I add AdditiveBlending , It's much better, but still have some problem.

[image]

Because I have another objects so I can't add `depthTest:false` , how can I solve this problem?

below is the code and the texture

[image]

```
var geometryBig = new THREE.Geometry();
var meshBig = new THREE.PointCloud(geometryBig, new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
    size: 4,
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    // depthTest: false,
    transparent: true,
    sizeAttenuation: true,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
        "img/particle.png"
    ),
}));
```

Comment: The suggestion by @gaitat to set `material.alphaTest` is the correct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your PointCloudMaterial:

`depthWrite: false`

[image]

Comment: seems that's works, but what exactly `depthWrite: false` mean?

Comment: When you set it to false, it has no effect on the depth buffer anymore. I cant give you a detailed explaination about why this works, sorry.

Comment: Thanks I mean what's the difference between `depthTest`

Comment: I still have more question about glow and texture , Could you give me a Email or IM , that I can ask more question ? many thanks

Comment: Please join #three.js on freenode for more unconstrained talk or ask your questions on Stackoverflow, if I can come up with a solution I will answer it :)